# Erro ao mostrar conteúdo de um BD mysql por meio de uma API em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, api

Ao criar uma API para consumo posterior recebo este erro: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\wamp64\www\Teste React com API\full\src\api\ClassCarros.php on line 9

Estou tentando mostrar o todos os dados de um banco de dados criado no phpmyadmin

Abaixo segue meu código:

Arquivo de conexão com o Banco de Dados:

```
<?php

abstract class ClassConexao{

#conexão com o banco de dados
    public function conectaDB(){
        try{
            $Con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:8080;dbname=react","root","");
            return $Con;
        }catch (PDOException $Erro){
            return $Erro->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Arquivo de manipulação e mostragem dos registros do banco de dados:

```
<?php

include("ClassConexao.php");

class ClassCarros extends ClassConexao{

    #Exibição dos carros em um json
    public function exibeCarros(){
        $BFetch=$this->conectaDB()->prepare("SELECT * FROM carros");
        $BFetch->execute();

        $J=[];
        $I=0;

        while($Fetch=$BFetch->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $J[$I]=[
                "Id"=>$Fetch['Id'],
                "Marca"=>$Fetch['Marca'],
                "Modelo"=>$Fetch['Modelo'],
                "Ano"=>$Fetch['Ano']
            ];
            $I++;
        }

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        echo json_encode($J);
    }
}

?>
```

o meu index.php:

```
<?php

include("ClassCarros.php");
$Carros=new ClassCarros();
$Carros->exibeCarros();

?>
```

Já tentei de tudo, colocar "__" no contructor ("exibeCarros()") colocar um return, mas nada funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo seu report de erro, sua função conectaDB() é uma string. Verifica se esta retornando uma conexão. Pois no report diz que o prepare esta sendo chamado em uma string.

Comment: Verifiquei e conforme os códigos postados, não consigo encontrar a solução do erro. Pelo que posso ver, a função conectaDB() não é uma string.

Comment: qual o resultado retornado em $BFetch? Acredito que seja algo com a sua conexão. Uma sugestão nomes de variaveis começam sempre com letra minusculas, letras maiusculas são reservadas a classes como a ClassCarro. Voce pode encontrar mais sobre isso aqui https://php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/